# A piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Definitions:

> - A piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be written as $\boldsymbol{\varphi}_1[a_1,b_1] \cup \boldsymbol{\varphi}_2[a_2,b_2]\cup \dots\cup \boldsymbol{\varphi}_N [a_N,b_N]$, with each $\boldsymbol{\varphi}_i:[a_i,b_i] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ a parameterization of a smooth curve, and where each end point $\boldsymbol{\varphi}_i(b_i)$ corresponds with the next starting point $\boldsymbol{\varphi}_{i+1}(a_{i+1})$.
> - A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a sequence $R_1,R_2,\dots$ of rectangles with sides parallel to the coordinate axes such that
>
>   1. $X \subseteq R_1 \cup R_2 \cup \dots$
>   2. $|R_1|+|R_2| + \dots < \varepsilon$, with $|R_i|$ the area of rectangle $R_i$.

My notes proceed with stating that a piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is  a null set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to understand to intuiton behind this theorem. Is there an easily understandable explanation behind it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not a proof; it just helps the intuition.

It is sufficient to consider a smooth curve, since a finite union of null sets is again a null set.

A smooth curve $\phi:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}^2$ has finite length $L>0$. Given an $N\gg1$ you should be able to cover it with  $N$ squares of side length $4{L\over N}$, say. These squares have a total area $$N\cdot\left(4{L\over N}\right)^2={16L^2\over N}\ .$$
Given an $\epsilon>0$ we can make the right hand side $<\epsilon$ by choosing $N$ large enough.

One therefore can say that the basic reason for the intended theorem is the fact that the dimension of ${\mathbb R}^2$ is $1$ greater than the dimension of ${\mathbb R}$, and similarly when ${\mathbb R}^2$ is replaced by ${\mathbb R}^n$.